# Shield Icons on Google Results Page

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, https

[image: Three different shield icons on google search]

The shield icons (circled) appear on my Google search results. My question is - if you have a site that's already https (and shows as such in the search results) what other action do you need to take so that the icon changes from a ? to a tick.

I can't seem to find any information relating to this or what the criteria is...

Comment: Does hovering the mouse over an icon show any tips or hints to where it's coming from?

Comment: No - when you hover over them it becomes part of the url link.

Comment: My tution-officer has those with saome security software.

Answer (score 20):

I am almost certain that those shield icons are not a Google Search feature, as I have never seen or heard of them before and cannot find any mention of them on the internet. If my hunch is correct, the icons are being shown to you by an extension that is installed in your browser, likely an antivirus, firewall or other "security" extension.

Check your list of installed browser extensions and you should be able to figure out which one is injecting these icons into your search results. Needless to say, if they are being injected by a niche browser extension then they are not an SEO concern.

Comment: I can confirm with 100% certainty that those shielded icons are not a Google Search Feature. If it was a test the community would have flipped out on Twitter and every guru under the sun would have a click-bait article up about it.

Comment: @MikeCiffone When searching for features (new) in google I always look for traces of the two thing you mentioned!

Answer (score 15):

This looks similar to the [Avast Browser Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/avast-online-security-pri/gomekmidlodglbbmalcneegieacbdmki), as mentioned on [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/green-check-mark-on-google-search/356305):

> [image: "This website is safe" on hover]

Only people who have this extension will see these shields. If I recall, it's not difficult to accidentally install this extension when installing Avast Antivirus, and the Chrome store reports it has "10,000,000+ users". There are other extensions that do the same thing, such as [Norton Safe Web](https://us.norton.com/feature/safe-web) and [Kaspersky Protection](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/tip-of-the-week-kaspersky-protection/11629/).

There is precious little information I have found out there on what exactly it takes to get the green shield. I do know that users of the plugin can rate your website as safe or unsafe, and likely that is a factor. Many of the websites I remember seeing without the green shield were obscure and likely had few to any ratings.

Comment: Only the color of the tick of the green shield is different.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy True, and plugins like this tend to update their interface, so what you see now won't be what you see in the future.

Comment: Obviously, I knew it.

Answer (score 9):

Traced them to AVG! According to their [Getting Started](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlname=Use-AVG-Online-Security) guide:

> The AVG Online Security browser extension displays information about the browsing quality of the websites you visit based on ratings from other users.
>
> Click the AVG Online Security icon to the right of your address bar to see one of three possible ratings:
>
> - This website is safe: other users rated the website positively.
> - This site may be untrustworthy: other users rated the website negatively.
> - Unknown site: the website does not have enough ratings to determine its trustworthiness.

I've clicked that I trust my own websites although they still show as a question mark - I suspect that it would need a number of 'thumbs up' before any changes happen.

I use Google Chrome (hence why I thought it was Google related). My concern is that other people who have the same extension activated (and I don't recall ever selecting this) might be put off clicking on one of my sites without a green tick, especially if one of my competitors does have it.

Comment: ***right** of your address bar*? not as left in the question?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy: there's no mention of the address bar in the question.

Comment: I said what is in the answer?! this answer of course seems not right as this is something that you get **after you visit a website** as opposed to what the question asks, **in the google search results**. IMO you should, as I quoted what was in the answer, should direct this to the answer writer not me.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard See for yourself: https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en&urlname=Use-AVG-Online-Security

Answer (score 6):

In all of my years I have never seen those shields before in the SERP's. I agree with Maximillian Laumeister that they are either a browser extension or some sort of security software on your computer.

I tried to find the exact plugin or program that would display those and cant find anything in the Chrome or Firefox extension web stores.